# Updating An Image on All instances of a website

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, raspberry-pi

So I have a Raspberry Pi controlling my Garage door. The Pi is running an apache webserver. I also have a camera connected to the raspberry pi and I want to be able to update the images from the camera. Currently I have the following code:

garage.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>The House Garage Controls</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Garage.php" method="get">
  <input type="submit" value="Open/Close Garage" style="width:1000px; height:150px;font-size:80px;border-radius: 25px;
background-color: 2DA3A7;" >
</form>
 <div id="doorImage">
    <img src="doorStatus.jpg" alt="Garage Door Picture From Camera" height="1000" width="1000">
 </div>
 <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var $container = $("doorImage");
        $container.imagefill('doorStatus.jpg')
        var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
            $container.load('doorStatus.jpg');
         }, 5000);

    }); 
        </script>
<form action="takeImage.php" method="get">
  <input type="submit" value="Update Picture" style="width:1000px; height:150px;font-size:80px;border-radius: 25px;
background-color: 2DA3A7;" >
</form>
</body></html>
```

And takeImage.php takes an image:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('raspistill -n -o /var/www/doorStatus.jpg');
echo "Output = ".$output;
header("Location: garage.html");
?>
```

When I view garage.html on my computer running chrome it updates the image when I click the update picture button. However on my android phone when I am on garage.html it doesn't update the picture unless I re-open the page. I am wondering how I would make it so that all devices viewing garage.html would see the same most recent image. I have been told that AJAX is the way to do this but I haven't found any code snippets that do something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a cache issue.

You can fix that (prevent caching) for example by adding a unique query string to the url.

Something like:

```
var curDate = new Date();
$container.load('doorStatus.jpg?time=' + curDate.getTime());
```

You could also configure your server to not cache these images.

Comment: This works across both devices! Thanks! However I still need to refresh the page for it to take effect. for example if I take a picture on my computer I need to refresh my phone for it to show up. Is it possible to do this out the refresh? I guess that is where I would need to start reading up on AJAX if it isn't a quick fix.

Comment: @sTr8_Struggin `.load()` is actually an ajax call. But you have some inconsistencies here, you start with an image tag and after your first ajax call, you have replaced that html image with a real image. You should replace the `src` attribute of your image tag instead and not the complete container contents.

Comment: @sTr8_Struggin Note that if you want to change the `src` attribute, you will have to let `.load()` go and use a more complete ajax method like `$.get()` or `$.ajax()`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Android browser is caching the image (which is standard behaviour). I'd suggest changing the name of the image each time (for instance using a timestamp), then having the page find the newest image. That would prevent caching issues (as it's not a new version of the same file).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will work on putting something like that together to test it out. I will post it if it does the job. Will that in principle work across all devices viewing the site?